# How can i have a transparent background in a pyside QWidget, but keep its children opaque

Tags: python, css, qt, pyqt, pyside

I have an widget that contain a lot of children , i want to set its background transparent , but keep its children opaque.

I'am using PySide 1.2.1  win7

I have try something like this:

---

self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground,True);

---

self.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgba(40,40,150,150);border:0px;")

---

but it dosen't work for me . It make the whole widget transparent . I want to keep the children opaque. Can someone help me ? Thank you so much. Here is my code , thanks for help.

---

```
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

class M_SCROLL_GRID_WIDGET(QWidget):
    # This is a common ui class .
    def __init__(self,column_count):
        super(M_SCROLL_GRID_WIDGET, self).__init__()

        self.column_count = column_count

        self.visible_widget_list = []

        self.scroll_widget = QWidget()

        self.scroll_area = QScrollArea()
        self.scroll_area.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.scroll_area.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.scroll_area.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll_area.setWidget(self.scroll_widget)

        self.main_layout = QGridLayout()

        self.main_layout.setSpacing(0)

        self.scroll_widget.setLayout(self.main_layout)
        self.main_layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        master_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        master_layout.addWidget(self.scroll_area)

        self.setLayout(master_layout)

        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgba(40,40,150,150);border:0px;")


    def Get_Widget_Count(self):
        return len(self.visible_widget_list)


    def Add_Widget_To_Vis_List(self, widget):
        self.visible_widget_list.append(widget)


    def Remove_Widget_To_Vis_List(self, widget):
        self.visible_widget_list.remove(widget)


    def Remove_All_Widgets(self):
        for i in reversed(range(self.main_layout.count())):
            widget = self.main_layout.itemAt(i).widget()
            widget.setParent(None)


    def Clean_Visible_List(self):
        self.visible_widget_list = []


    def Refresh(self):

        for widget_index in xrange(len(self.visible_widget_list)):
            r_position =  widget_index      / self.column_count
            c_position = (widget_index + 1) % self.column_count
            if c_position == 0:
                c_position = self.column_count
                         self.main_layout.addWidget(self.visible_widget_list[widget_index], r_position, c_position)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    caofan = M_SCROLL_GRID_WIDGET(3)

    btn_list = []

    caofan.Remove_All_Widgets()
    for a in xrange(50):
        btn = QPushButton(str(a+1))
        btn_list.append(btn)
        caofan.Add_Widget_To_Vis_List(btn)

    caofan.Refresh()

    caofan.show()

    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Your example contains too much clutter. Can you remove everything that is not essential? Also I don't see the transparent widget. Everything is blue and black...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the real problem is that the style sheet you specify is propagating to the child widgets.

So, remove...

```
self.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgba(40,40,150,150);border:0px;")
```

and override `QWidget::paintEvent` with something like...

```
def paintEvent(self, event):
    painter = QPainter(self)
    painter.fillRect(self.rect(), QColor(40, 40, 150, 150))
```